# How to add C libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: programming, serial-port, arduino

I want to add `Arduino-serial-lib.h` in order to achieve serial communication between my system and Arduino. How can I add this library in my system?

Answer (score 1):

Just download it to your directory project. You could use gcc include directive to set the specific path to that library: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html.

If you are using the Eclipse or any other IDE you could change compiler (includes) options.

Answer (score 1):

To add your file to the system add it to /usr/include as root (sudo)

Comment: `/usr/local/include` should be preferred for libraries not managed by the OS.